# GridDB: Invalid Container Name encountered while attempting to test GridDB docker container

Tags: docker, griddb

I am new to docker and I have been following [the official instructions](https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/docker/#installation-docker) to install GridDB via command line. I'm using Windows.

There are a series of commands to follow and they have all worked except when I get to the command to run an example container that connects to the main GridDB container.

Here's the series of commands and output, to show that I have followed the directions properly:

```
D:\>docker network create griddb-net
cd97f791460e247e1673ff25f2c8c120bf9b18499f5913e797e66c096a4c3f5a

D:\>docker run --network griddb-net --name griddb-server -d -t griddbnet/griddb
18d75f54cd3434b618153d8e7ffed856009f88c34da1011204a3657d6951bd37

D:\>docker run --network griddb-net --name griddbnet/griddb-react-crud -p 2828:2828 -d -t griddbnet/griddb-react-crud
docker: Error response from daemon: Invalid container name (griddbnet/griddb-react-crud), only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I copied the commands exactly as they appear in the instructions so I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong?